# Android Error Execution ZXing Lector codigos QR integrado

Tags: android, android-studio

Pues he aquí mi problema !

Cuando intento construir mi APK me sale el siguiente error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/zxing/aztec/AztecDetectorResult.class
```

Adjunto mi gradle.app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ruben.codqrneodavid"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.6'

    compile ('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.zxing'
    }
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'

}
```

Como puedo solucionarlo ??

Comment: Hei @SamGold Probaste lo que comento ?

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo al error:

> duplicate entry: com/google/zxing/aztec/AztecDetectorResult.class

deberías de excluir cuando se contenga `com.google.zxing`, dentro de tu `build.gradle` :

```
compile(contain com.google.zxing library) {
   exclude group: 'com.google.zxing'
}
```

Comment: Perdon por el retraso !! Pues acabo de pegarlo en mi proyecto y no me funciona, me da fallo en "  (contain com.google.zxing library)  "